# JVM Crash while running java program with rJava(to integrate with R)

Tags: java, r, eclipse, jvm, jri

I am relatively new to R programming and I am trying to call an R script from my Java code using rJava in Eclipse. My program looks something like this:

```
package pkg;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class Temp {

public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {

    Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);

    ClassPathResource rScript = new ClassPathResource("pkg/printEx.r");
    System.out.println(rScript);
    rengine.eval(String.format("source('%s')",rScript.getFile().getAbsolutePath()));

    REXP result = rengine.eval("greeting");
    System.out.println("Greeting from R: "+result.asString());
    }
}
```

The R script printEx.r is a normal R file to print that returns some String:

```
 printExample <- function() {
  s <- "hey"
  s
}
```

When i tried running the Java program in Eclipse JVM Crashes giving the error like this:

```
class path resource [pkg/printEx.r]
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077c17a24,    pid=8196, tid=0x0000000000002690
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x17a24]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\posingh3\workspace\RWithJava\hs_err_pid8196.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The log file is as shown below:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077c17a24, pid=8196, tid=0x0000000000002690
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x17a24]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000023be800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9872, stack(0x0000000002640000,0x0000000002740000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000002e204ed

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000272e500, RBX=0x0000000002740000, RCX=0x000000000272e5a0, RDX=0x0000000000000580
RSP=0x000000000272e280, RBP=0x000000000272e400, RSI=0x000000000272e980, RDI=0x0000000002a1017c
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000002a10000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000000272e500
R12=0x00000000027446a0, R13=0x000000001922dc80, R14=0x0000000002e204ed, R15=0x0000000002a10170
RIP=0x0000000077c17a24, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000272e280)
0x000000000272e280:   0000000002740000 000000000272e980
0x000000000272e290:   00000000000127bc 0000000000000000
0x000000000272e2a0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000272e2b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000272e2c0:   0000000000000002 0000000000000000
0x000000000272e2d0:   000000000272e980 0000000002a10000
0x000000000272e2e0:   000000000273f7c0 0000000000000005
0x000000000272e2f0:   0000000002a10170 0000000002740000
0x000000000272e300:   0000000050b1c200 0000000002726000
0x000000000272e310:   0000000050517f61 00000000503d0000
0x000000000272e320:   0000000050bfcba0 000000000273f450
0x000000000272e330:   000000006c74be34 000000000272e400
0x000000000272e340:   00000000509a09d4 0000000050b1c200
0x000000000272e350:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000272e360:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000272e370:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000077c17a24)
0x0000000077c17a04:   41 8b 7f 08 45 33 d2 49 03 f9 4c 89 54 24 48 f6
0x0000000077c17a14:   47 03 0f 0f 85 3d 0c 00 00 4c 8b a5 98 00 00 00
0x0000000077c17a24:   41 0f b6 0e 4c 89 64 24 60 49 8b d6 80 f9 48 0f
0x0000000077c17a34:   84 e0 03 00 00 0f b6 c1 24 fe 3c 48 0f 84 97 15 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000272e500 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
RBX=0x0000000002740000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
RCX=0x000000000272e5a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
RDX=0x0000000000000580 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000272e280 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
RBP=0x000000000272e400 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
RSI=0x000000000272e980 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
RDI=0x0000000002a1017c is at code_begin+28 in 
[CodeBlob (0x0000000002a10110)]
Framesize: 0
BufferBlob (0x0000000002a10110) used for CodeCache Exception Handler
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000002a10000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000000272e500 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023be800
R12=0x00000000027446a0 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000001922dc80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018d60800
R14=0x0000000002e204ed is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000002a10170 is at code_begin+16 in 
[CodeBlob (0x0000000002a10110)]
Framesize: 0
BufferBlob (0x0000000002a10110) used for CodeCache Exception Handler


Stack: [0x0000000002640000,0x0000000002740000],  sp=0x000000000272e280,  free space=952k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x17a24]
C  [msvcrt.dll+0xe5a3]
C  [R.dll+0x625ad]
C  [R.dll+0x616bf]
C  [R.dll+0x61f00]
C  [R.dll+0xb5344]
C  [R.dll+0xb5f3e]
C  [R.dll+0xb71eb]
C  [R.dll+0xb9819]
C  [R.dll+0xba18c]
C  [jri.dll+0x1695]
C  0x0000000002a28a57

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniParse(Ljava/lang/String;I)J+0
j  org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.eval(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/rosuda/JRI/REXP;+53
j  org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.eval(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/rosuda/JRI/REXP;+3
j  pkg.Temp.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+56
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000018d60800 JavaThread "Thread-0" [_thread_blocked, id=12108, stack(0x0000000019130000,0x0000000019230000)]
  0x0000000018d5f000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8984, stack(0x00000000195a0000,0x00000000196a0000)]
  0x0000000018cec800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9360, stack(0x00000000193c0000,0x00000000194c0000)]
  0x00000000174ff800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10556, stack(0x0000000019270000,0x0000000019370000)]
  0x00000000174f6800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10468, stack(0x0000000018be0000,0x0000000018ce0000)]
  0x00000000174f5000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12152, stack(0x00000000185f0000,0x00000000186f0000)]
  0x00000000174f1800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10896, stack(0x0000000018a60000,0x0000000018b60000)]
  0x00000000174da800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1916, stack(0x00000000188c0000,0x00000000189c0000)]
  0x0000000017493800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1976, stack(0x0000000018720000,0x0000000018820000)]
=>0x00000000023be800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9872, stack(0x0000000002640000,0x0000000002740000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001748c000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000184e0000,0x00000000185e0000] [id=11932]
  0x0000000018d79800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000197e0000,0x00000000198e0000] [id=12224]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 36864K, used 2543K [0x00000000d6e00000, 0x00000000d9700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 31744K, 8% used [0x00000000d6e00000,0x00000000d707bdc0,0x00000000d8d00000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d9200000,0x00000000d9200000,0x00000000d9700000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8d00000,0x00000000d8d00000,0x00000000d9200000)
 ParOldGen       total 84992K, used 0K [0x0000000084a00000, 0x0000000089d00000, 0x00000000d6e00000)
  object space 84992K, 0% used [0x0000000084a00000,0x0000000084a00000,0x0000000089d00000)
 Metaspace       used 3251K, capacity 4664K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 363K, capacity 424K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011dd0000,0x00000000121b0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000119ab000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000050be64f0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012970000, 0x0000000014848000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014848000, 0x0000000016720000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000460000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1218Kb max_used=1218Kb free=244542Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002a10000, 0x0000000002c80000, 0x0000000011a10000]
 total_blobs=325 nmethods=75 adapters=163
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.524 Thread 0x0000000018cec800   71       3       java.lang.StringBuilder::<init> (7 bytes)
Event: 0.524 Thread 0x0000000018cec800 nmethod 71 0x0000000002b3b8d0 code [0x0000000002b3ba40, 0x0000000002b3bcf0]
Event: 0.524 Thread 0x0000000018cec800   72       1       java.net.URL::getRef (5 bytes)
Event: 0.524 Thread 0x0000000018cec800 nmethod 72 0x0000000002b3be10 code [0x0000000002b3bf60, 0x0000000002b3c070]
Event: 0.525 Thread 0x0000000018cec800   74       3       java.lang.String::toLowerCase (439 bytes)
Event: 0.527 Thread 0x0000000018cec800 nmethod 74 0x0000000002b3c0d0 code [0x0000000002b3c400, 0x0000000002b3dc58]
Event: 0.527 Thread 0x0000000018cec800   73       1       java.nio.Buffer::limit (5 bytes)
Event: 0.527 Thread 0x0000000018cec800 nmethod 73 0x0000000002b3eb10 code [0x0000000002b3ec60, 0x0000000002b3ed70]
Event: 0.527 Thread 0x0000000018cec800   75       1       java.net.URL::getQuery (5 bytes)
Event: 0.527 Thread 0x0000000018cec800 nmethod 75 0x0000000002b3edd0 code [0x0000000002b3ef20, 0x0000000002b3f030]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (1 events):
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x00000000023be800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002b2a764 method=org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;ZLorg/rosuda/JRI/RMainLoopCallbacks;)V @ 78

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.047 Thread 0x00000000023be800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d6e07cc0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\srŒE‡«T¨?
Event: 0.048 Thread 0x00000000023be800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d6e07fa8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u92\6642\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\j

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$FormatString done
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$FixedString done
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$FormatSpecifier
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$FormatSpecifier done
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$Flags
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$Flags done
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$Conversion
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formatter$Conversion done
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formattable
Event: 0.531 loading class java/util/Formattable done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fd90000 - 0x000000013fdc7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000077c00000 - 0x0000000077daa000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077ae0000 - 0x0000000077bff000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd9b0000 - 0x000007fefda1a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefe720000 - 0x000007fefe7fb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe5a0000 - 0x000007fefe63f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feffc30000 - 0x000007feffc4f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefdf50000 - 0x000007fefe07d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000779e0000 - 0x0000000077ada000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff990000 - 0x000007feff9f7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefdd40000 - 0x000007fefdd4e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff8c0000 - 0x000007feff98a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefbce0000 - 0x000007fefbed4000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe640000 - 0x000007fefe6b1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feffee0000 - 0x000007fefff0e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe490000 - 0x000007fefe599000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fee8790000 - 0x000007fee8837000     C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcApi.dll
0x000000006fa30000 - 0x000000006fa3b000     C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcThe.dll
0x0000000079210000 - 0x00000000792e2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000503d0000 - 0x0000000050c66000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef9520000 - 0x000007fef9529000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefe6c0000 - 0x000007fefe70d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe710000 - 0x000007fefe718000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefb3b0000 - 0x000007fefb3eb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefc8b0000 - 0x000007fefc8bc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077dc0000 - 0x0000000077dc7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000747a0000 - 0x00000000747af000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006bf20000 - 0x000000006bf49000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\java.dll
0x0000000052bf0000 - 0x0000000052c06000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefead0000 - 0x000007feff859000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feffc50000 - 0x000007feffe53000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd990000 - 0x000007fefd99f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000062d80000 - 0x0000000062da6000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\rJava\jri\jri.dll
0x000000006c700000 - 0x000000006e078000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\R.dll
0x0000000064e80000 - 0x0000000064eda000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\Rblas.dll
0x00000000641c0000 - 0x00000000641e5000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\Riconv.dll
0x0000000063540000 - 0x00000000635b0000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\Rgraphapp.dll
0x000007feffa00000 - 0x000007feffa97000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x000007fee8ac0000 - 0x000007fee8ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x000007fefb840000 - 0x000007fefb896000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000000006e5c0000 - 0x000000006e5e8000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\utils\libs\x64\utils.dll
0x0000000064a40000 - 0x0000000064a53000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\methods\libs\x64\methods.dll
0x000000006fc80000 - 0x000000006fd89000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\grDevices\libs\x64\grDevices.dll
0x0000000063740000 - 0x0000000063785000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\graphics\libs\x64\graphics.dll
0x0000000071100000 - 0x00000000711a4000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\stats\libs\x64\stats.dll
0x000000001ad70000 - 0x000000001b009000     C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\Rlapack.dll
0x000007fee8c60000 - 0x000007fee8d85000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\lib\ext\zipfs.jar 
java_command: pkg.Temp
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\posingh3\workspace\RWithJava\src;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\rJava\jri\JRI.jar;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\rJava\jri\JRIEngine.jar;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\rJava\jri\REngine.jar;C:\Users\posingh3\Downloads\spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\gradle-2.13-all\gradle-2.13/bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\rJava\jri\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\git;;C:\Users\posingh3\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse;
USERNAME=posingh3
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23392)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 61 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 8077544k(4278400k free), swap 16153232k(10584992k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_92-b14), built on Mar 31 2016 21:03:04 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu May 19 15:07:24 2016
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I am using Windows-7,64-bit and Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).
Any help would be welcomed..:)

Comment: Close eclipse and delete .metadata folder. Then open eclipse and import project again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it still isn't working!

Comment: Did it work? If yes, I'll add it as a answer.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the log file?

Comment: I already added the log file above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems so there was some problem with ClassPathResource.
When I compiled without using the exact path it compiled without an error.I am still not sure what caused the JVM to crash in the first place but the following code snippet worked for me:

```
package pkg;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class Temp {

public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {

    Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--vanilla" }, false, null);

    rengine.eval("source('C:/Users/posingh3/workspace/RWithJava/src/pkg/printEx.R')");

    REXP value =re.eval("toString(a<-simple())");
    System.out.println(value.asString());
  }
}
```

Besides you need to convert the return string into an R string using "toString()" function to be able to process it properly.